# Android Animate Alpha during Drag Animation Now Working

Tags: android, animation, viewdraghelper

I've added the drag functionality to a component using ViewDragHelper and I'm trying to add a fade animation to the component so that when the user touches the screen and drag it, it changes the component's alpha using an animation.
The problem is that the animation waits for the user's interaction to stop and then it applies the animation so that during the component transition, you can't see the alpha animation,

```
override fun clampViewPositionVertical(child: View, top: Int, dy: Int): Int {
        if(top < verticalRange)
            return verticalRange
        backgroundView.animate().alpha((backgroundView.alpha - 0.05).toFloat()).duration = 10
        return top
    }
```

The on touch Event:

```
 override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
            return if (isDragEnabled && (isControlScreenLayoutTarget(event) || isMoving)) {
                viewDragHelper.processTouchEvent(event)
                true
            } else {
                super.onTouchEvent(event)
            }
        }
```

Comment: You should add the codes of `onTouchEvent` to make it clearer.

Comment: @DuyKhanhNguyen I've edited the question and added the onTouchEvent

Comment: There are no connections between your blocks of code, we can't know how/where do you call `clampViewPositionVertical`. You should add enough codes that should the flow.

Comment: @DuyKhanhNguyen I will add more code if you need it, but the bug doesn't have anything to do with the drag flow. I added some logs to clampViewPositionVertical function and I know that the function is called, but the alpha animation doesn't work until the user touch/ interaction stops.

Answer (score 0):

You should not start your animation in `clampViewPositionVertical()`. That method is called to return the boundaries where the view will move, actually scroll.

Instead you should wait until view is released, in other words, start your animation as soon as the range check is fulfilled in the `onViewReleased()`.

Comment: Yeah, I could do, but that's not what I want to achieve, I like to change the alpha as the user scrolls the view.